# Filter by object and related object in linq using same condition

Tags: c#, linq

In an MVC app that I'm working on I have two models, lets say `Foo` and `FooBar`. `Foo` is one-to-many related to `FooBar` (`FooBar`s have a property that stores `Foo`'s Id).

I have saved some fancy `Where` condition as a static function in my service:

```
public static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> FancyCondition(int input)
{
    return(x => x.Prop1 == input);
}
```

I wrote it as such, because I was expecting to reuse it a lot. And it does work when filtering `Foo` objects. I use it like this:

```
var results = dbContex.Foo.Where(FancyCondition(4));
```

But now I need to apply this condition to filter objects of type `FooBar` and I can't quite figure out how to do it. Of course I could copy the condition adjusting all the fields and properties from `x.PropertyName` to `x.Foo.PropertyName`, but that sounds like a bad idea.

---

Let me rephrase my problem. I have condition for filtering objects `Foo` and I have objects of type `FooBar` that are always related to just one `Foo` object. I want to filter objects of type `FooBar` using the same condition, but I don't know how to achieve that using a single piece of code.

Comment: You need to add more information. What does `Prop1` have with a `FooBar`, if a `Foo` has many `FooBar`s?

Comment: @Groo `Foo` might have many `FooBar`s, but that's irrelevant since `FooBar` will always have just one `Foo`. The condition involves comparing several string properties of `Foo` and string properties of its related objects (but not `FooBar`s).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return(x => x.Prop1 == input);`? (Double equals sign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked about this problem with someone else in the office and he said "And how would you solve it if it was a SQL query?". This instantly lead me to a solution, I can do this using `Join`.

```
IQueryable<FooBar> foobars = dbContex.FooBar.Join<FooBar, Foo, int?, FooBar>(dbContext.Foo.Where(FancyCondition(4)), x => x.FooId, y => y.Id, (x, y) => x);
```

So my mistake here was thinking how to solve it using linq, rather than how to solve it using SQL and then translate it to linq.

Of course, I'm open for alternative suggestions on how this can be achieved (especially ones that are better than mine).

Answer (score 0):

As it is strongly typed, you would need a converter (e.g. an implicit conversion operator) which would be able to convert Foo to FooBar. Or you could use dynamic.